Weird behavior with ScrollView in SwiftUI
I am currently touching up on my SwiftUI knowledge and I'm building this task screen. However there is this weird section with the ScrollView that I can't explain on how to remove (gray area above tab bar on first screenshot). It seems to disappear when fully scrolled to the bottom of the app.
Note: I have a custom TabBar and in my ContentView all of the Views are in a ZStack
struct DailyTaskView: View {
    var tasks: [Task]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gBlack.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(tasks) { task in
                        TaskItemView(task: task)
                            .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TaskItemView: View {
    var task: Task
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 40) {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(color: .white.opacity(0.1), radius: 3)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                HStack(spacing: 8) {
                    Text(task.title)
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Label("11:22 PM", systemImage: "clock")
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                }
                
                Text(task.description)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .font(.callout)
            }
//            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(15)
            .background(task.tint, in: .rect(topLeadingRadius: 15, bottomLeadingRadius: 15))
//            .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 20))
            .strikethrough(task.isCompleted, pattern: .solid, color: .white)
        }
        .padding(.leading)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection: Int = 0
    @State private var tasks: [Task] = sampleTask.sorted(by: {$1.date > $0.date})
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.gBlack.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack() {
                DateHeaderView()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color(Color.gBlack))
                
                TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
                    DailyTaskView(tasks: tasks)
                        .tag(0)
                    Text("Tab 2")
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gBlack)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .tag(1)
                    
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                TabBarView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
}



Attempted converting to List to see if it was ScrollView specific
Played with .frame() with no luck
Verified there wasn't any additional padding that could intervene

You're using a custom tab bar, but you've not hidden the native one, so it's still there. When you scroll, it has a translucent background. See this answer for a way to verify and solve.

This was actually the correct answer that worked for my particular scenario. Hiding the native tabbar solved my issue without converting my custom tabbar to a page

Pleased to hear you found a solution. Changing the .tabViewStyle to .page also adds "swipe-to-switch" functionality, so this might be a reason to choose... or not choose... that technique.

Try adding .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) to your TabView(selection: $tabSelection).
TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
    DailyTaskView(tasks: tasks)
        .tag(0)
    Text("Tab 2")
        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.black)
        .tag(1)
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) // <--- here

Note, Swift already has a Task defined, change yours to something else (MyTask)
otherwise you will confuse yourself and the compiler.
